# c#, Textbox.Text encoding

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, textbox

I have code:

```
string text = sampleTextBox.Text;
```

and I'm wondering in what encoding text is? Is it utf16 (as it is string) or maybe it is my operating system encoding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's all Unicode, basically - there's no conversion between the .NET textual types (`char`/`string`) and binary going on, so there's no encoding to worry about.

You *potentially* need to worry about surrogate pairs to get from the UTF-16 textual representation of `char` and `string` to full UTF-32, but that's slightly different to the normal encoding issues.

Philosophically, a textbox contains text, not binary data. You should only be thinking about encodings when there's a conversion to a binary format - such as a file.

Answer (score 3):

String variables in .Net are UTF-16 internally. Encoding comes into play when you want to output the string outside your program: a file, a webpage,  or over the network in some fashion.